# Multiplicaciones en formulario dinámico PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Muy buen día a toda la comunidad.
Tengo un problema, estoy un poco atorado con esto, y probablemente me puedan ayudar. Se los agradecería mucho.

Estoy creando un formulario para subir órdenes de compra a una base de datos. He llegado al punto en donde el usuario va a solicitar productos o servicios, y para ello, estoy generando un conjunto de campos de manera dinámica. La cuestión es que, por supuesto, el código debería de multiplicar la cantidad por el precio unitario, sin embargo, dado que los campos dinámicos son idénticos, la multiplicación está saliendo mal: Lo que está haciendo ahora es que multiplica todos los campos por sí mismos y coloca un gran resultado en el primer text, dejando a los demás solos. No estoy generando los campos mediante javascript, dado que dos de ellos son 'select' y además uno de ellos se está poblando desde una base de datos usando código PHP, y por lo tanto, al intentar poner ese código dentro de una variable de Javascript, resulta truncado. Encontré una solución muy ingeniosa, pero me temo que le hace falta algo que permita alterar los nombres de los campos, y, por supuesto, que el javascript multiplique individualmente cada conjunto de campos creado dinámicamente.

Vean cómo está haciendo la multiplicación:
[Captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJj5r.png)

Aquí está el código para crear los campos dinámicamente:

```
    <div id="productos" >
<?php require_once("InputDinamico.php") ?>
</div>
<div class="btn-action float-clear">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="agregar_registros" value="Agregar Mas" onClick="AgregarMas();" />
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="borrar_registros" value="Borrar Campos" onClick="BorrarRegistro();" />
<span class="success"><?php if(isset($resultado)) { echo $resultado; }?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Este es el Javascript que agrega o quita el conjunto de campos:

```
 <script>
function AgregarMas() {
    $("<div>").load("InputDinamico.php", function() {
            $("#productos").append($(this).html());
    }); 
}
function BorrarRegistro() {
    $('div.lista-productos').each(function(index, item){
        jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(item).remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Y este es el contenido de InputDinamico.php, que contiene los campos:

```
    <div class="lista-productos">
<input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" />
<label for="item">Item:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="item" name="item">
   <?php
            $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "******"); 
mysql_select_db("vpm_proveedores", $link);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $link);  
$registros=mysql_query("select id, item
                       from items",$link) or
  die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
?>         
   <option value="0" selected>- Seleccione uno -</option>
   <?php while ($reg=mysql_fetch_array($registros))
     { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $reg['id'];?>"><?php echo $reg['item'];?></option>  
     <?php }?>  
                  </select><br>

   <label for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control monto" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" onkeyup="multi();">
   <label for="unidad_medida">Unidad de Medida:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="unidad_medida" name="unidad_medida[]">
   <option selected value="pza">Pieza(s)</option>
   <option value="lt">Litro(s)</option>
   <option value="kg">Kilo(s)</option>
   <option value="mts">Metro(s)</option>
   <option value="svc">Servicio</option>
   </select>   
   <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion[]" value=""/>
   <label for="precio_unitario">Precio unitario:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control monto" id="precio_unitario" name="precio_unitario[]" onkeyup="multi();">
   <label id="Costo">
      <input type="text" name="Costo" disabled value="0">
   </div>
```

Y el script para multiplicar:

```
    <script>
function multi(){
    var total = 1;
    var change= false; //
    $(".monto").each(function(){
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
            change= true;
            total *= parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    // Si se modifico el valor , retornamos la multiplicación
    // caso contrario 0
    total = (change)? total:0;
    document.getElementById('Costo').innerHTML = total;
}
</script>
```

Ojalá pudiera haber alguien que me de un norte con esto. Agradezco mucho desde ahora. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Has probado darle un console.log(total) cada vez que calculas el total ?? Asi verias como se supone que calcula todo.

Comment: Por cierto, para poder ayudarte, necesitas crear un codigo del error, he intentado con lo que tienes, pero no funciona. Lo que necesitas es un [mre].